# How can I create a Facebook fan page that displays content only after user joins it?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I'm sure everyone using Facebook is familiar with this type of fan pages, where you have to click the "Become a fan" button before it will display any content to you.

How can I do this on my own fan page? I've tried to google it, but I don't really know what to look for.

Comment: Facebook developers wiki is down right now. Even so this is a programming issue, you should know the basics of programming to achieve this, there is no, click a check-box option while you create a page for that.

Comment: @Trufa: yes I know I need to do something with probably FBML and javascript, but since there are so many pages of this type, there must be a simple guide to do this ... I just don't know what to search for

Comment: Yes there is, I remember there was a simple explanation in the facebook developers wiki, tried it once and worked, but now, as soon as it is up again I can point you to it. I'll search for a replacement anyhow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is something called a Fan Gate.

> A Facebook fan gate is also known as and often referred to as the reveal tab or welcome tab. Sound familiar? In fan pages for Facebook, the fan gate is the initial tab (or landing page) new visitors to your page land on. It’s not for returning fans, strictly for new visitors. Once they “Like” your fan page for facebook, and become an official fan the fan gate tab turns into different content that is available to fans only.
>   [src](http://www.designpax.com/blog/what-is-a-facebook-fan-gate/)

You use to be able to make them yourself with some FBML and the FBML app on your page, but that app is no longer available and has been replaced with the iFrame app.. thus requiring a bit more coding to get it to work.. or going a pay solution.

Here is a link to a step by step php iFrame free solution
http://www.chilipepperdesign.com/2011/02/15/reveal-fan-gate-like-gate-facebook-iframe-tab-tutorial-with-php

Here is a link to a step by step solution provided by Wildfire http://www.marismith.com/iframes-facebook-app-fan-gate-wildfire/

M

Comment: This is correct! +1